# iOS OS 10.3.3 with Alamofire POST (content type JSON) Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I have been working on an iOS app and calling my webservices using Alamofire 4.0 / Swift 3.1 / Xcode 8.3.3.

Everything seemed to be working fine until my iPhone was at OS 10.0. I updated my iPhone today to 10.3.3 and all of a sudden my web services stopped working.

Here's the code I have been working with:

```
class func verifyLoginCredentials(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ type: ResponseType , _ response : Int, _ message: String) -> Void) {

        var serviceURL = baseURL + "&task=login&email=" + username + "&pwd=" + password
        serviceURL = serviceURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        let url = URL(string: serviceURL)
        let authHeader = ["":""]

        print(url!)

        request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: authHeader).responseJSON(options:

        JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) { (serverResponse) -> Void in
            switch serverResponse.result {
            case .success(let JSON):

                debugPrint(JSON)

                if (JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int == 1 {
                    completion( ResponseType.kresponseTypeSuccess,(JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int, "")
                    // Set User Session
                    CFunctions.setLoginSession(JSON as AnyObject)
                } else {
                    completion( ResponseType.kresponseTypeSuccess,(JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int, (JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "response") as! String)
                }

            case .failure(let error):

                let dataString = String(data: serverResponse.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print("verifyLoginCredentials Request failed with error: \(String(describing: dataString))")
                completion(ResponseType.kResponseTypeFail, error._code, "Service failed")

            }

        }
    }
```

This is what I get in console:

```
http://198.1.109.253/~ecc2014/api/?verifyKey=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&task=login&email=user@yopmail.com&pwd=secret
verifyLoginCredentials Request failed with error: Optional("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.27 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2k mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at 198.1.109.253 Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n")
```

I would like to mention one more thing here. My web services were being called from old domain (http://www.exoticcarclub.net/api/?) previously. Now that my web services have been moved to a new server and it's domain name has not been pointed yet, so they gave me http://198.1.109.253/~ecc2014/api/? to replace with. I think this might also be the culprit.

Can someone point out what is going on in OS 10.3.3? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _stopped working_? Do you get an error or what?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be anything related to your code. This is either a backend issue or the request has changed when migration the server and you need to update your code to match the new request format.

Comment: Well, i figured it out. I just removed `let authHeader = ["":""]` line and removed `headers: authHeader` parameters from request line, and finally removed `(options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)` and it worked.

Comment: So yeah, as suspected this was a configuration error. The `mutableContainers` option is useless in `Swift`, you control mutability of the `JSON` object by either declaring it with the `let` or `var` keyword.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing it out David.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out myself.

1. Just removed `let authHeader = ["":""]` line.
2. Removed `headers: authHeader` parameters from request line.
3. Finally removed `(options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)`.

Comment: I made the same mistake of passing blank parameters in headers. Thanks..